# Menu doesn't slide left as it should

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

This code has one arrow at the left side. When clicked, `#sidebar` should move with `#contact` exactly `4em`s to the right. When clicked again, both objects should slide back to their original position.

However, when `#contact` is clicked, nothing appears to happen, I tried debugging it quite a couple of times, with no apparent result.

```js
$(function() {
 var contact = $("#contact");
 var sidebar = $("#sidebar");
 
 if (contact.class = "fa-caret-right") {
  contact.click(function() {
   sidebar.animate({left: "-4em"});
   contact.removeClass("fa-caret-left").addClass("fa-caret-right").css({"padding-left":".2em","padding-right":"0"});
  });
 } else if(contact.class = "fa-caret-left") {
  contact.click(function() {
   sidebar.animate({left: "0"});
   contact.removeClass("fa-caret-right").addClass("fa-caret-left").css({"padding-left":".1em","padding-right":".2em"});
  });
 }
});
```

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poiret+One|Smythe);

i.tiny{font-size:2em;}
i.small{font-size:3em;}
i.medium{font-size:4em;}
i.large{font-size:5em;}

body {
 margin: 0;
}

header {
 background-color: gray;
 font-family: "Poiret One";
 font-size: 2em;
 padding-top: .3em;
 padding-bottom: .3em;
 text-align: center;
}

main {
 background-color: white;
 height: calc(100vh - 2.6em - 4em);
}

#sidebar {
 position: fixed;
 left: -4em;
 width: 4em;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
 background-color: black;
 color: gray;
 border-top-right-radius: 5px;
 border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
}

#sidebar i {
 display: block;
 margin: auto;
 width: 1em;
}

#sidebar i:first-child {
 width: .88em;
 margin-top: 10px;
}

#sidebar i:nth-child(3) {
 width: .88em;
}

#sidebar i:nth-child(4) {
 position: fixed;
 left: 2em;
 top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
 background-color: black;
 width: .5em;
 padding-left: .2em;
 border-top-right-radius: 50%;
 border-bottom-right-radius: 50%;
}

#sidebar i:last-child {
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}

footer {
 background-color: gray;
 height: 4em;
}
```

```html
<body>
 <header>
  <div>
   Title
  </div>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.css">
 </header>
 <main>
  <section id="sidebar">
   <i class="fa fa-facebook-official small"></i>
   <i class="fa fa-envelope small"></i>
   <i class="fa fa-skype small"></i>
   <i id="contact" class="fa fa-caret-right tiny"></i>
   <i class="fa fa-tty small"></i>
  </section>
 </main>
 <footer>
 </footer>
</body>
```

Please try to resolve the problem. Thank you!

And if you have any questions or comments please **comment** on this question. Please do not write an answer to ask something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a number of errors in your code.

- `contact.class = "fa-caret-right"` should be
  `contact.hasClass("fa-caret-right")`
- You are removing and adding the wrong classes.
- You are binding your click events on load when the element has the
  class `fa-caret-right` meaning that your close click is never bound
  to the element.

If you correct your syntax errors and move your `if` statement inside the click event you may have more luck...

```js
$(function() {
 var contact = $("#contact");
 var sidebar = $("#sidebar");

 contact.click(function() {
  if (contact.hasClass("fa-caret-right")) {
   sidebar.animate({
    left: "0"
   });
   contact.removeClass("fa-caret-right").addClass("fa-caret-left").css({
    "padding-left": ".2em",
    "padding-right": "0"
   });
  } else if (contact.hasClass("fa-caret-left")) {
   sidebar.animate({
    left: "-4em"
   });
   contact.removeClass("fa-caret-left").addClass("fa-caret-right").css({
    "padding-left": ".1em",
    "padding-right": ".2em"
   });
  }
 });

});
```

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poiret+One|Smythe);

i.tiny{font-size:2em;}
i.small{font-size:3em;}
i.medium{font-size:4em;}
i.large{font-size:5em;}

body {
 margin: 0;
}

header {
 background-color: gray;
 font-family: "Poiret One";
 font-size: 2em;
 padding-top: .3em;
 padding-bottom: .3em;
 text-align: center;
}

main {
 background-color: white;
 height: calc(100vh - 2.6em - 4em);
}

#sidebar {
 position: fixed;
 left: -4em;
 width: 4em;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
 background-color: black;
 color: gray;
 border-top-right-radius: 5px;
 border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
}

#sidebar i {
 display: block;
 margin: auto;
 width: 1em;
}

#sidebar i:first-child {
 width: .88em;
 margin-top: 10px;
}

#sidebar i:nth-child(3) {
 width: .88em;
}

#sidebar i:nth-child(4) {
 position: fixed;
 left: 2em;
 top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
 background-color: black;
 width: .5em;
 padding-left: .2em;
 border-top-right-radius: 50%;
 border-bottom-right-radius: 50%;
}

#sidebar i:last-child {
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}

footer {
 background-color: gray;
 height: 4em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
 <header>
  <div>
   Title
  </div>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.css">
 </header>
 <main>
  <section id="sidebar">
   <i class="fa fa-facebook-official small"></i>
   <i class="fa fa-envelope small"></i>
   <i class="fa fa-skype small"></i>
   <i id="contact" class="fa fa-caret-right tiny"></i>
   <i class="fa fa-tty small"></i>
  </section>
 </main>
 <footer>
 </footer>
</body>
```

---

By modifying your css slightly to use a `transition` you could simply your code *a lot* and your animation will be much smoother...

```
#sidebar {
    ...
    transition: all .2s ease;
}

#sidebar.active {
    left: 0;
}
```

---

```js
var contact = $("#contact");
var sidebar = $("#sidebar");

contact.click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('fa-caret-right fa-caret-left');
    sidebar.toggleClass('active');
});
```

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poiret+One|Smythe);

i.tiny{font-size:2em;}
i.small{font-size:3em;}
i.medium{font-size:4em;}
i.large{font-size:5em;}

body {
 margin: 0;
}

header {
 background-color: gray;
 font-family: "Poiret One";
 font-size: 2em;
 padding-top: .3em;
 padding-bottom: .3em;
 text-align: center;
}

main {
 background-color: white;
 height: calc(100vh - 2.6em - 4em);
}

#sidebar {
 position: fixed;
 left: -4em;
 width: 4em;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
 background-color: black;
 color: gray;
 border-top-right-radius: 5px;
 border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
    transition: all .2s ease;
}

#sidebar.active {
    left: 0;
}

#sidebar i {
 display: block;
 margin: auto;
 width: 1em;
}

#sidebar i:first-child {
 width: .88em;
 margin-top: 10px;
}

#sidebar i:nth-child(3) {
 width: .88em;
}

#sidebar i:nth-child(4) {
 position: fixed;
 left: 2em;
 top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
 background-color: black;
 width: .5em;
 padding-left: .2em;
 border-top-right-radius: 50%;
 border-bottom-right-radius: 50%;
}

#sidebar i:last-child {
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}

footer {
 background-color: gray;
 height: 4em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<header>
  <div>
    Title
  </div>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.css">
</header>
<main>
  <section id="sidebar">
    <i class="fa fa-facebook-official small"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-envelope small"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-skype small"></i>
    <i id="contact" class="fa fa-caret-right tiny"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-tty small"></i>
  </section>
</main>
<footer>
</footer>
```

Comment: Gives solution, explains solution, **and** gives alternative! This is one of the best answers I have had so far

Comment: Glad you found it useful.